# AMD Radeon HD 8790M driver issue with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon

I haven't used my built in laptop video card in years and its been fine, but now doing some modelling in FreeCAD and it is painfully slow, so I would really, really like to get my video card working.

My video card is not being used by Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for michael: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:37 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c40000-f7c5ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:39 memory:f5800000-f5bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

UPDATE: Updated Grub setup:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
DRI_PRIME=1

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Checking DRI_PRIME:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: OLAND (, LLVM 14.0.5, DRM 2.50, 5.15.0-41-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-e8fc5cc 2022-06-22 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-e8fc5cc 2022-06-22 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-e8fc5cc 2022-06-22 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I think part of the issue is the card is a `FirePro W4170M` but being picked up by linux as a `Radeon HD 8790M`.

Comment: This driver won't install. And it is not needed at all. The manuals you are trying to follow were released in 2015.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*; cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the reply, please see the bottom of the post for the additionally info.

Comment: All looks good there, but a kernel module either of radeon or amdgpu is not loaded for some reason.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried commented out the line `# blacklist radeonfb` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf` and rebooted but the graphics card is still unclaimed.

Comment: Please don't try random actions. You will break your system.

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and check if a module loads there.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry, I needed to perform a `grub-update` for the new changes to take place. Now it the unclaimed message is gone. However `grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*;` does not print out any modules. I will try boot from live cd thanks. I think the graphics card fan is spinning constantlly really fast, laptop getting hot, which I think is why I disabled the graphics card years ago with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"` (which I have now reverted).

Comment: So is the issue resolved? You disabled the GPU yourself.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes I disabled it years ago cause it never worked, just go hot. I am currently in a live environment, heres the result: `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -E 'amdgpu|radeon' /etc/modprobe.d/*;
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist radeonfb`, it looks the same to me.

Comment: Forget about the `grep` it is good it is not showing anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed BaseMark GPU to test the graphics card because FreeCAD was just as slow, and sure enough, my Graphis card is not listed there. Its still not working.

Comment: As I said, you need `DRI_PRIME=1`.

Comment: I added `DRI_PRIME=1` after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` in `/etc/default/grub`, then did `sudo update-grub` then rebooted, and same behaviour. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, don't add it there. You run it in a terminal.

Comment: Your initial question has been answered. how to use the AMD GPU is another question.

Comment: Try to add `radeon.runpm=0 ` to grub, like that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=0"`. And remove `#` from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137935/discussion-between-pilot6-and-run-the-race).

Comment: It is working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `radeon.modeset=0` from `/etc/default/grub` and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

That will fix the issue.

But you'll need to use `DRI_PRIME=1` to use the AMD GPU.

You can check if the AMD GPU is working by running:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

To fix `radeon` errors add `radeon.runpm=0` to grub like that

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=0"
```

and run `sudo update-grub` again and reboot.

Now if you want to run a program on the AMD GPU, start it with `DRI_PRIME=1`. Example:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 firefox
```

You can add `DRI_PRIME=1` to the program `.desktop` file, to use it permanently.

If you want to run all programs on AMD, add `DRI_PRIME=1` to the end of `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: I added the ouput of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, seems to say `Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer`, I also added a comment about `FirePro W4170M`